# I filtered two arrays and return the similar items

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, filter

I got the solution But, i can't understand the function named **'isInSecondArray()'** and its parameter **'item'**. How that works.

```
function justCoolStuff(firstArray, secondArray) {

//The problem is underneath this comment.
      function isInSecondArray(item){
            for(let i = 0; i<secondArray.length; i++){
                  if (secondArray[i] === item){
                        return true
                  }
            }

            return false 
      }

    return firstArray.filter(isInSecondArray)
}


const coolStuff = ['gameboys', 'skateboards', 'backwards hats', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'pogs', 'my room', 'temporary tattoos'];

const myStuff = [ 'rules', 'fruit-by-the-foot', 'wedgies', 'sweaters', 'skateboards', 'family-night', 'my room', 'braces', 'the information superhighway']; 
strong text
console.log(justCoolStuff(myStuff, coolStuff))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compares two arrays—concretely, it keeps only those items of the first array that the second array contains.

To do so, your function `justCoolStuff` takes both arrays. Then it declares a function called `isInSecondArray`. This function is then passed to the invocation of the filter function in the line `firstArray.filter(isInSecondArray)`.

The `filter` function iterates over `firstArray`. As it iterates, it passes each item from `firstArray` into the `isInSecondArray` function. For example, if `firstArray` contains five elements, then `isInSecondArray` will run five times, once with each item. At every iteration, the `isInSecondArray` function iterates over the second array and compares the item from the first array with the current item from the second array. `filter` then returns a new array with only those items for which `isInSecondArray` returned a truthy value.

In other words, you have two loops, one implicit in `filter`, another explicit in the `for` loop. The `for` loop is nested in the `filter` loop. If your arrays have five and four items, respectively, there will be a total of 4 * 5 = 20 iterations. (That number could be reduced significantly if you used sets instead of arrays, but admittedly that's not what you asked about.)

[filter function reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

In this example that you posted, you have a function defined within a function. So that function (`isInSecondArray()`) can only be executed within the `justcoolStuff()` function.

So on the final line, when we run the `justCoolStuff` function with `myStuff` passed in as the first array, and `coolStuff` passed in as the second array, what happens is this:

- the function `isInSecondArray` is defined and setup so it's ready to execute, if it gets called
- then we run the filter method on `firstArray`, passing in the `isInSecondArray` method (defined earlier in the function) as an argument.

`filter` is a JS method that works on Arrays. The way to use it is you pass it a callback function. See [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for a nice simple example that uses an arrow function.

So filter iterates over the items in `myStuff` (since this is the first of the two arrays passed in). For every item in `myStuff`, it runs the `isInSecondArray` function. `isInSecondArray` iterates over all the items in `secondArray` and if one of them is the same as the item of `myStuff` that we're checking, then it returns true.

When the callback function passed into `filter` returns true, then that element is allowed to be returned as part of the final array/object. When the callback function (i.e. `isInSecondArray`) returns false, then that item isn't returned as part of the final array / object.

I hope that's clear. The important thing to know here is that `filter` takes a (callback) function, and depending on what the callback function returns will determine which values get output as part of the final returned array.